# "По деревенским масштабам" — вводное ли выражение?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Является ли вводным это выражение и нужно ли его выделять запятыми?
В таком, например, предложении:

В большом, по деревенским масштабам, доме жило человек двенадцать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не вводное сочетание, но можно считать пояснительным оборотом, думаю, что запятые уместны.

Если пояснительного смысла автор не вкладывает, то и запятых нет.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "по деревенским масштабам" **близко по значению к вводным словам**, указывающим **на источник сообщения**:  по мнению,  на  взгляд, с точки зрения и т.д.  К этой же группе можно отнести   сочетания с **оценочным значением** "по меркам кого/чего-либо", например: Он явился, когда на скатерти было уже расставлено царское, **по меркам восемнадцатого года**, угощение.

В приведенном примере мы также **имеем сочетание с оценочным значением**, позиция которого удобна для обособления: В большом, **по деревенским масштабам,** доме жило человек двенадцать. Похожий пример: Главный виновник этого грандиозного, **по деревенским масштабам**, строительства   уже давно живёт в Челябинске.

В тоже время  обособление таких выражений, **как и других вводных слов**, может являться **авторским решением,** в данном случае обособление сочетания "по деревенским масштабам" способствует  его **смысловому выделению**.